# I want to make 2 app sharing same database.

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb

One app will write data according to items it need and 2nd app will fetch data from database acoording to their category . I am using amazon aws . Is there anyone who is familiar with amazon aws or know how to do it. 
I just need guidance or step how to proceed

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a web backend which is connected to your AWS and do all the manipulation in your DB. This web backend will host endpoints (APIs) for both of your apps so that you can trigger the functions when required.

I am not sure but i think dynamoDB provides direct interactions also. You can check JAVA code at following link

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CodeSamples.Java.html

If direct interactions is not possible you can always do it via your own web backend.